# multiplicar varlores en formularios de filas dínamicas

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo un formulario en html el cual agrega dinámicamente lineas, en cada linea esta el nombre del producto, cantidad, precio unitario y total.

Lo ideal seria que se algo asi (Tomates 10 15 150) en donde tengo el producto que es tomate, con 10 unidades, el precio unitario es de 15 y el precio total es de 150, si agrego una nueva línea pues lo ideal es que haga lo mismo, sin embargo no lo hace, solo hace la operación de la primera linea

Las funciones para agregar las nuevas lineas es esta

```
    <script>
function AgregarMas() {
    $("<div>").load("InputDinamico.php", function() {
            $("#productos").append($(this).html());
    }); 
}
function BorrarRegistro() {
    $('div.lista-producto').each(function(index, item){
        jQuery(':checkbox', this).each(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $(item).remove();
            }
        });
    });
}
</script>
```

Este es el formulario

```
<div id="row" class="text-center">   
    <div class="col-sm-1">&nbsp; Nro.</div>     
    <div class="col-sm-5 center-block" > Descripción</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2" >Cantidad</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 center-block" >Costo Unitario</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 center-block" >Costo Total</div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div id="productos">
    <?php require_once("InputDinamico.php") ?>        
</div>
```

Y esta es funcion de la multiplicación y la linea que agrego, este es el InputDinamico.php

```
<script>
function multi(valor){
  m1 = document.getElementById("txt_campo_1").value;
  m2 = document.getElementById("txt_campo_2").value;
  r = m1*m2;
  document.getElementById("spTotal1").value = r;
}
```

```
<div class="lista-producto">
<ul class="list-group">
   <li class="row list-group-item">        
        <div class="col-sm-1 center-block">
            <input class="center-block" type="checkbox" name="item_index[]" /></div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <input class="form-control center-block" type="text" name="pro_nombre[]" /></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <input class="form-control center-block" type="text" name="pro_precio[]" value=0 id="txt_campo_1" onchange="multi(this.value);" /></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <input class="form-control center-block" type="text" name="pro_cantidad" value=0 id="txt_campo_2"  onchange="multi(this.value);"/></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 center-block">
            <input class="form-control center-block" type="text" name="pro_total" id="spTotal1" style="width:110px;"/></div>

    </li>
 </ul> 
</div>
```

Como se podria solucionar eso? Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: La función que estás usando para ejecutar la multiplicación siempre toma los valores de los elementos con IDs: **txt_campo_1** y **txt_campo_2**, por lo que siempre vas a estar operando con los elementos de la primera fila. Sin ver la función con la que insertas nuevas filas no sabría decirte que más posibles errores podrías estar teniendo.

Comment: @PHPMyguel, ahi agregue la funcion para agregar las filas, gracias por la ayuda

Comment: ¿Y qué tienes en **InputDinamico.php**? Súbelo también porque sin eso no puedo ver el **HTML** que usas para agregar una fila.

Comment: Perdon el InputDinamico.php es la funciones  multi y la parte del formulario, los dos ultimos fragmentes de codigo, gracis @PHPMyguel

Comment: Con la función **load()** estás cargando todo lo que tienes en **InputDinamico.php** dentro del elemento **#productos** esto puede dar lugar a tal número de errores que es imposible de determinar sin ver el fichero **php** por completo. Sin meterme de cabeza en ese lodazal podría decirte que aparentemente el problema que tienes está en que al llamar a la función que usas para agregar una fila, esta nueva fila genera elementos que tienen los mismos IDs que la anterior. Aunque yo que tú miraría tutoriales de como generar contenido dinámico porque me da que andas un poco perdido.

Comment: @PHPMyguel vieras que el codigo com tal lo baje de aqui https://www.baulphp.com/inputs-dinamicos-usando-jquery-y-php/ me pareció bastante completo ahi todo sale correcto, con la diferencia de que no hace el calculo de la multiplicacon que necesito pero si agrega las filas y guarda en labase de datos, como lo ves?